# Difference between nohup and ctrl+z command in Linux

Tags: linux, unix

I want to run jobs in the background so that I can logout from terminal once any job is started. I know two ways

1) run job and then press **ctrl+z**  and then enter **bg**

```
mysqldump -uroot -p dbname  > dbname.sql
```

2) using nohup to run job and then press **ctrl+z** and then enter **bg**

```
nohup mysqldump -u root -p dbname  > dbname.sql 2>&1
```

I want to know the difference between above two commands and which one is best in which scenario.

Comment: You should use tmux.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Running your process as a job constrains your job to the current session. So if you run

```
$ start_running_job &
$ exit
```

The job will stop when you exit.

Pressing Control-Z has the same effect as the lines above.

Running nohup places the job so that it survives the end of the current session. So if you run

```
$ nohup start_running_job &
$ exit
```

The job will continue running.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with answer provided...

"nohup" basically runs your command/script in back-end mode on server itself and it is not related to your current login session while putting "&" just puts the script in background and remains connected to your current login session. In any case you can use fg to bring back script/command.

Which is good for you, for this it depends how you are accessing your server and for how long your script is gonna take to complete. Say your script will take more amount of time and your current login session remains ideal it will close down and script will get killed if you have only given &. So much of the time just give nohup and don't worry it.